# Is there a way to terminate only the first command in a sequence of commands?

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

When using tmux I use the wait-for feature where the tmux session is getting notified after the finishing of a command. Sometimes however I want to terminate the command sequence without terminating the wait-for part so the original script doesn't hang.

Basically, if I have:

```
command 1; command 2
```

hitting Ctrl-C exits both where I mainly want to exit command 1 but continue executing command 2 (which is the wait-for acknowledgment so the script doesn't hang).

Is there a way to do that?

I already tried:

```
command 1 || command 2
```

But Ctrl-C still exits both.

Comment: Separate lines mean the second wont wait until the first finishes. Which is the action I am waiting to be notified on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try running command 1 in the background and trap the signal that <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> sends.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
(command 1) &                 # Runs c1 in the background
pid=$!                        # Stores the PID of the subshell
trap "kill -INT $pid" SIGINT  # Makes Ctrl+C kill the background process
wait                          # Waits for completion of c1
trap - SIGINT                 # Restores the default behaviour of Ctrl+C
command 2                     # Runs the second command
```

Comment: That's the direction I was thinking. The one-liner with subshells doesn't trap the interrupt. Well done.

Comment: Does exiting the background command set the status to be false? I depend on reading the status to decide whether to move with the next actions in the script or not.

Comment: `wait` returns the exit status of the command it waits for. But if you kill it with Ctrl+C, it will return `130` (128 + 2 for SIGINT).

Answer (score 2):

To let the command exit but the script continue on Ctrl-C, just set a no-op sigint trap:

```
trap "true" INT
sleep 30
echo "Continuing"
```

If you want to restore the behavior of killing the script, you can use `trap - INT`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should ensure that if you press ctrl-C, command1, plus any child processes that it may have, get the SIGINT.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use "set -m" to test if "-m" option is currently set
# If set, this will ensure that any subprocesses are started
# as process group leaders (we'll need this later)

if [ -z "${-//[^m]/}" ]  # -m option not already set
then
    set -m
    setm=1
else
    setm=0
fi

# launch the command and capture its pid
command1 &
pid=$!

# install a trap so that if SIGINT is received, then every
# process in the process group of which command1 is leader
# is sent a SIGINT (note the "-" before $pid)
trap "kill -INT -$pid" SIGINT

# wait for command1 to finish (ignoring any other previously launched
# children that finish meanwhile)
wait $pid

# undo "set -m" setting as appropriate
if [ $setm -eq 1 ]
then
    set +m
fi

# cancel the trap
trap - SIGINT

# and carry on
command2
```

For example, if `command1` is itself a shell script, then the command that is being run by that shell script should be properly terminated.

A slight side-effect of using the `-m` option is that if you do press ctrl-C, then you will receive a message such as:

```
[1]+  Interrupt               command1
```

This may be deferred until after the next command completes.  You could insert a short sleep before `command2` (e.g. `sleep 0.1`) so that any such notification is delivered at the end of the sleep (before command2 runs) rather than after command2.